# Pearson's Correlation Coefficient as a clustering criterion: why should it be close to -1?

Tags: correlation, clustering, k-means, pearson-r

Let's say we have a dataset $x = (x_1, x_2, ..., x_n)$ where each data point is assigned to one of $m$ clusters.

Let $D = \{d_{ij}\}$ be the $n\times n$ distance matrix where $d_{ij} = d(x_1, x_j)$.

Let $A = \{a_{ij}\}$ be an $n\times n$ adjacency matrix where $a_{ij} = 1$ if $x_i$ and $x_j$ belong to the same cluster; $0$ otherwise.

Using Pearson's correlation coefficient to measure the clustering quality in k-means, $r_{AD} = {\rm Cov}(A,D) / σ_A σ_D$, that is:

$$
\frac{\sum_{i, j = 0}^{n} (a_{ij} - \mu_A) (d_{ij} - \mu_D)}
{\sqrt{\sum_{i, j = 0}^{n} (a_{ij} - \mu_A)^2 \sum_{i, j = 0}^{n} (a_{ij} - \mu_D)^2}}
$$

Why would the clustering results be better if $r_{AD}$ is close to $-1$?

Comment: The better cluster partition is when close points belong to same cluster while distant points belong to different clusters. Since your proximity is _distance_ matrix but the cophenetic binary proximity is _similarity_ (1=in the same cluster > 0=in diff. clusters), it follows that a better partition entails r towards -1.

Comment: Pearson correlation as internal clustering criterion, also called point-biserial correlation, is usually computed by the formula which corresponds to coding opposite to yours: 0=in the same cluster, 1=in different clusters, when D is distance, not similarity. Then r closer to +1 means the better clustering.

Comment: Are you suggesting that, if rAD = 1 or -1, then each point is its own cluster ?

Comment: As you wish. As tradition, r is computed so it is towards +1, not -1, if clustering is good.